# Interface, Classes and Sub-Classes inheritance

Tags: java

I have a parent class `Fruit` and sub-classes `FruitUnit`, `FruitWeight` and `FruitVolume` describing the different types of how fruit can be bought.

I must create a interface to implement the method `payFruit()` as all child classes of fruit must implement this.

```
interface IFruitPayment {
    double payFruit();
}
```

Assuming the method for calculating the `payFruit()` is different for each child class (quantity*price, units*price, weight*price), how can i create any parent `Fruit` object and access the method payFruit() from child classes?

Implementing the method `payFruit()` returning 0 in the parent class solves the issue because the child classes can override it but it doesn't seem right.

Suppose i have an arraylist of fruits and i want to iterate them to get the value of the method `payFruit()`.

What is the best and cleanest way to achieve this?

**Introduction:**

In a fruit shop, all fruit has a name and a base price. The store sells fruit in three ways: unity, weight and volume. The total price is calculated by multiplying the base price by the number of units, by weight or by volume, as the case may be. Any type of fruit (eg banana, orange, apple) can be sold by unit, by weight or by volume.It is intended the development of a Java Project, with a hierarchy of classes. `The FruitUnit, FruitWeight and FruitVolume classes inherit from the Fruit class`. There should also be a Basket class that represents the various fruits to be purchased. This class should include methods for:

1. Insert in the basket a purchase of a given fruit;
2. Calculate the total value of the fruits purchased;
3. Calculate the total amount spent for a given type of fruit (the name of the fruit)

For compatibility with classes of other projects, the method that performs the calculations of the amount to be paid, to be used in the various classes, will have the name payFruit, return type double and no parameters. This method must be declared in an interface.

**Note**:
i know this may seem particular to my case and not very helpful for others but i find this class hierarchy a bit confusing to work with.

Comment: That class hierarchy doesn't make sense. Those subclasses don't represent kinds of fruit.

Comment: Let `Fruit` implement `IFruitPayment` and make the class `abstract`. Then you can use the `payFruit()` method on a `Fruit` object because the method is defined there (actually in the interface).

Comment: As previously stated, your subclasses don't pass the is-a test.  FruitUnit is-a Fruit, FruitWeight is-a Fruit?  I don't think so.

Comment: You say you must create an interface?  Is this for a class?

Comment: Along with the confusing class hierarchy, why would you need the interface in this case? Couldn't you just make `Fruit` abstract and make the method `payFruit()` abstract? Unless you have other non-fruit classes needing `payFruit()`, using an interface does not make much sense.

Comment: I updated the question. I too think it's a bit confusing and i am unsure. Nobody in the class seems to be having trouble dealing with this introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically you want your subclasses to implement the `IFruitPayment` interface.

If each of your subclasses implement that interface you can use them as that interface.

```
List<IFruitPayment> fruitPayments = new ArrayList<>():
        fruitPayments.add(new FruitUnit());
        fruitPayments.add(new FruitVolume());
        fruitPayments.add(new FruitWeight());
        for(IFruitPayment payment:fruitPayments) {
            System.out.println(payment.payFruit());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a different structure here. It's hard to conceive of a `FruitUnit` subclass of `Fruit`. This is because `IFruitPayment` *is NOT* a fruit. It's a separate interface that you want your subclasses to implement.

With this said, you can declare that `Fruit` implements `IFruitPayment`, make `FruitUnit`, `FruitWeight` and `FruitVolume` *extend* `IFruitPayment`, and have subclasses of `Fruit` implement one of these...

```
abstract class Fruit implements IFruitPayment {}
```

Unless you need to check the specific implementation types, you should be able to get rid of these three interfaces as the API is provided by `IFruitPayment`. But otherwise:

```
interface FruitUnit extends IFruitPayment{}
interface FruitWeight extends IFruitPayment{}
interface FruitVolume extends IFruitPayment{}
```

And actual subclasses will implement the appropriate interface:

```
class Banana extends Fruit implements FruitWeight {
    public double payFruit() {...}
}

class Watermelon extends Fruit implements FruitVolume {
    public double payFruit() {...}
}

//etc.
```

Now there's a little redundancy here, IMO. If the sub-interfaces have a reason to be, maybe they should have a cleaner API of their own, such as by declaring methods specific to their own types. Here is a fabricated example just to illustrate the idea:

```
interface FruitUnit extends IFruitPayment{
    double getQuantityPrice();
    default double payFruit() {return this.getQuantityPrice();}
}
```

But unless this is needed, the three sub-interfaces are practically unnecessary.

Comment: Ty! I updated the question with an introduction. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do what was asked from me.

Answer (score 0):

For figuring out how much a fruit costs you really have two concerns:

1. A price per 'unit' of that fruit
2. For each fruit, how much of a 'unit' it is

A `Fruit` at the core (whether an abstract class or interface) just needs to provide a `double getUnit()` that all implementations have to implement. From there, it depends on how complex you want to get; If this is just a simple exercise, I'd consider adding two more methods - one that returns the price-per-unit, and another that gets the cost of the fruit (which just multiples them together).

You could argue that the price-per-unit isn't a concern of a `Fruit` though; in that case you might have a whole other service knows the price of each `Fruit`, and that's the one that can do the multiplication.

Edit: Volume, weight, color, etc are each individually important for particular implementations to calculate their "unit" value, but its up to you and the situation whether those are worth being on the public interface or not